# Qt GUI clickable Qframe or QWidget or Groupbox

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x

I have a problem with my code :/
My program needs to click a QFrame, QWidget or QGroupBox.
At the moment I use mouseReleaseEvent but it only works when my function doesn't have values set.

```
def testc(self,e):
 print(e)

#when I use this code:
self.frame.mousePressEvent = self.testc;
#it's okey
#but when I'm using
self.frame.mousePressEvent = self.testc("ssssss");
# after starting the function automatically performs a click not working
```

[image]
How can I make a clicking widget, frame or group-box?

My qt code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ar.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(571, 149)
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 120, 80))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(88, 169, 255);"))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("frame"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(17, 23, 91, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(Form)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 30, 120, 80))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 158, 160);"))
        self.widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("widget"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 81, 31))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(Form)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 30, 120, 80))
        self.groupBox.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(56, 30, 255);"))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox"))
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(7, 34, 101, 21))
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "clicable frame", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "click widget", None))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("Form", "GroupBox", None))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "click groupbox", None))
```

The point is that I want a group of objects in my QFrame. After clicking the QFrame I would like my program to write, after clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Create a function that does not take arguments

You have to assign a function to `mousePressEvent` and `self.testc("ssssss")` does (probably) not return a function.

What you can do is to create another function

```
def f(self):
    return self.testc("ssssss")
```

and assign

```
self.frame.mousePressEvent = self.f
```

For such one-liners it is often preferred to create *lambda*

```
self.frame.mousePressEvent = lambda: self.tests("ssssss")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a function to the frame's `mousePresseEvent` like so:

```
self.ui.frame.mousePressEvent = lambda event: print("ssss")
```

OR
If you want to create a separate function:

```
def frame_click(self, event):
        print(":)")
```

then assign the function to the event:

```
self.ui.frame.mousePressEvent = self.frame_click
```

Remember to include an `event` parameter as the mousePressEvent expects an event in the defined function.